# Why am I getting a 'Template Invalid License key' error while setting up CKEditor5 using Angular14?

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

## CKEditor5 EditorError: template-invalid-license-key

I have implemented a CKEditor5 in angular14 with Image Resize Options.

- **Code for Html**

```
    <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" (ready)="onReady($event)" name="description" id="editor"
         #description="ngModel" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>" [config]="editorConfig"
         [(ngModel)]="releaseNoteInformationObj.description"
         [ngClass]=
          "{ 'is-invalid-icon':(description.touched || releaseNoteForm.submitted) &&        (description.errors?.required) }" required>
    </ckeditor>
```

- **Code For TS**:

```
    import * as CustomBuild from 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';
      
    Editor = CustomBuild;
    
    editorConfig = {
    
        image: {
          // Configure the available styles.
          styles: [
            'alignLeft', 'alignCenter', 'alignRight'
          ],
    
          // Configure the available image resize options.
          resizeOptions: [
            {
              name: 'resizeImage:original',
              label: 'Original',
              value: null
            },
            {
              name: 'resizeImage:50',
              label: '25%',
              value: '25'
            },
            {
              name: 'resizeImage:50',
              label: '50%',
              value: '50'
            },
            {
              name: 'resizeImage:75',
              label: '75%',
              value: '75'
            }
          ],
    
          // You need to configure the image toolbar, too, so it shows the new style
          // buttons as well as the resize buttons.
          toolbar: [
            'imageStyle:alignLeft', 'imageStyle:alignCenter', 'imageStyle:alignRight',
            '|',
            'ImageResize',
            '|',
            'imageTextAlternative'
          ],
        },
    
        language: 'en'
    
     }
```

I am getting a 'Template Invalid License key' error while running an Angular Application although I have attached a screenshot below regarding my Error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nlOg.png)

- **Version for Dependecies**:

  "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^37.1.0",
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^37.1.0",
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload": "^37.1.0",
  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^37.1.0"

I have referred to the below article on Stackoverflow:-

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73956868/ckeditor5-angular-after-updating-angular-to-13-ckeditor5-angular-to-4-and-all](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have also added one variable called licenseKey: "licenseKey" in the ts file.

Comment: This is the manual how to do it: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/licensing/license-key-and-activation.html